# How to convert a max in the objective function, when we maximizes?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cplex, gurobi

How to rewrite the program

```
maximize max(2x, 3y)
s.t 0 <= x, y <= 1
```

So that an LP/MILP can solve it?

My actual objective function is
[image]

I'm new to LP, and I don't understand well how to use 'binary constraints'.

I'm learning with `PuLP` and `GLPK`.
In my production code, I will either use `CPLEX` or `Gurobi`.
Those these two support 'maximization of max' out of the box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Maximising the max" is inherently nonconvex.  You will need to use a MIP trick here.  And you must be able to get lower and upper bounds on the objects you're taking the max of in order to do so.  Any finite bound will do, but sharper bounds will give a tighter relaxation that will probably solve faster and be nicer numerically.

Suppose you've got the following problem, which is marginally more general than the one you gave:

```
maximize max(3x, 2y)
s.t.  0 <= x <= A, 0 <= y <= B.
```

Notice that `3x` is trivially bounded below by `0` and above by `3A`.  Similarly, `2y` is bounded below by `0` and above by `2B`.  Now you introduce two binary variables, `c_1` and `c_2`, and you ask that exactly one of them be `1`.  `c_1` corresponds to the choice of `3x` from the `max` and `c_2` corresponds to the choice of `2y` from the `max`.  Then you write

```
maximize z_1 + z_2
s.t.  z_1 <= 3A c_1
      z_1 <= 3x
      z_2 <= 2B c_2
      z_2 <= 2y
      c_1 + c_2 = 1
      0 <= x <= A, 0 <= y <= B
      c_1, c_2 binary
```

The first constraint "turns off" `z_1` so that it has zero contribution if the max is attaned by `2y`.  The second constraint limits `z_1` by `3x` in the case where the max is attained by `3x`.

Comment: Is there a documentation on this for a more extensive case? Let's say `maximize 
 max(a_1*x_1, a_2*x_2, ..., a_n*x_n)` ?

Answer (score 1):

If the objective was a minimization, you can use an auxiliary variable as follows:

```
minimize z
s.t. z >= 2x, z >= 3y, 0 <= x, y <= 1
```

If it's a maximization, below should work, where

`M` is a sufficiently large number;

`u_{1,2}_{1,2}` are a set of auxiliary variables that represent a "permutation" that sorts 2x and 3y.

```
maximize (z_1_2 + z_2_2)
s.t. 
z_1 = 2x
z_2 = 3y

z_1 = z_1_1 + z_1_2
z_2 = z_2_1 + z_2_2

u_1_1 + u_1_2=1
u_2_1 + u_2_2=1
u_1_1 + u_2_1=1
u_1_2 + u_2_2=1

z_1_1 <= M*u_1_1
z_1_2 <= M*u_1_2
z_2_1 <= M*u_2_1
z_2_2 <= M*u_2_2

z_1_1 + z_2_1 <= z_2_1 + z_2_2


0 <= x, y <= 1
u_{1,2}_{1,2} in {0,1}   //u_i_k are binary variables.
```

min and max of a bunch of numbers, unlike sum, is not a linear form, and I don't think CPLEX or MILP generally has a special form for this. In this particular example, a smaller number of binary auxiliary variables might be enough (instead of `u_{1,2}_{1,2}`), but in general, a permutation variable like this gives you the order of a sequence of numbers and allows you to pick any of them by rank (in your case the largest item).

Comment: I think you are missing the constraints `z=2x` and `z=3y`. Do you know how to add them?

Comment: Your problem is always infeasible or unbounded.

Comment: I was thinking about a minimization objective out of habit. A more complex model is possible as in the update.

Comment: The technique here can pick up not only the largest number, but also the median of a set of numbers.

Comment: `z_1_1 + z_2_1 <= z_2_1 + z_2_2` doesn't look right to me.  Otherwise, your solution appears sound.

Comment: z_1_1 + z_2_1 represents the smallest number, and z_2_1 + z_2_2 represents the second smallest. So, this constraint maintains the correct order.